# How to automatically sort JTable after adding new row?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to sort rows in JTable in ascending or descending order while adding new rows to JTable?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: actually after adding new row to the jtable i want table to be sorted automatically by checking the value of new row with all rows in jtable

Comment: again what exactly is the problem?, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for TableModel and just about a.m. issue with sorting after new row is added,

Comment: Sir,Let me explain,suppose a jtable contain name and age values, while adding new record with name and age,it should check age value with all records in jtable and then autosort the jtable in ascending or descending order of age column,how should i implement this ?

Comment: that happens automatically, so something is wrong with the code you are not showing :-) Take up @mKorbel's suggestion ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs whether or not you need to sort on multiple columns, you can add a TableModelListener to your table model, to execute custom behaviour when the table model changes. Just implement the

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
```

method to capture the event and sort the required collumn.  One way of doing this is to map work with an index map which refers to the data of the column you want to sort and resort the index map according to the column that you want to sort.

Comment: not, please not ...., how and who will put together those code with methods  before Java5 edges, before RowSorter

Comment: the question is a bit wobbly (read: just guessing here :-), it seems like the goal is to sort the view - which is handled just fine by the table itself

Comment: again there by default isn't required to call or toggle with RowSorter, and wouldn't be works in all cases for model based on HashMap, sure nobody knows